# Memory consumption of python ESL

Tags: python, freeswitch

I have written a ESL server, which controls call flow on FreeSWITCH server. The problem is that after the connection closes, the memory consumption does not decrease to normal. After some hundred connections are made to the server, its memory consumption goes to GBs and it has to be killed forcefully. I have pinpointed the issue to be of ESLconnection object. I have tried deleting the object and its instances using del, but to no avail. The code is as below:

ivrServer.py

```
import SocketServer
from ESL import *
import importlib
import sys
import threading
import traceback
import signal
import time

class ESLRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    #svr_ivr_log = None
    def setup(self):
        fd = self.request.fileno()
        self.con = ESLconnection(fd)
        self.svr_ivr_log.info("Client connected: %s" % str(self.client_address))

    def handle(self):
        ivr_script = importlib.import_module('script')
        ivr_script = reload(ivr_script)
        ivr_script.process(self.con)

    def finish(self):
        self.con.disconnect()

ESLRequestHandler.svr_ivr_log = logging('server')

SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer(('', 9090), ESLRequestHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

script.py:

```
def process(con):
    info = con.getInfo()
    uuid = info.getHeader('unique-id')
    con.execute('hangup', "NORMAL_CLEARING", uuid)
```

This would require ESL module of freeswitch compiled for your linux version. Let me know if I need to explain the procedure to do that. Python2.7 is being used here.

Comment: I had to replace Python-ESL with mod_python which allows you to run python code within FreeSWITCH without the need of sockets, as I was unable to find a resolution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From [SocketServer doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html?highlight=tcpserver):

> ...A new instance is created for each request.

Each request creates a new `ESLRequestHandler` instance.

In your `setup()`, you make a connection to the FreeSWITCH server, but you never close it after you finish handling the request. I suspect this is the source of the memory leak.

To close the connection to the FreeSWITCH server you do something along the lines of:

```
class ESLRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    #svr_ivr_log = None
    def setup(self):
        fd = self.request.fileno()
        self.con = ESLconnection(fd)
        self.svr_ivr_log.info("Client connected: %s" % str(self.client_address))

    def handle(self):
        pass  # your code for interacting with the FreeSWITCH server here

    def finish(self):
        self.con.disconnect()  # close the connection
```

Comment: I tried disconnect and even hangup in finish, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I replaced the compiled ESL library with latest freeswitch version, but that only slowed the process of increasing memory consumption. At one point, it does go on to use around 30Gb of system memory, post which I have to kill the process.

Comment: I would suggest posting more of your code. It's hard for people to help without more info

Comment: I had deducted the issue to be of ESL after eliminating all other modules used in my code. So, I guess it doesn't make sense to include the additional code. However, I'll still change the code to reflect the actual mechanism.

Comment: We have same issue, python eating all memory. I have to restart every two day to free all used memory by python. did you get any solution?

Comment: Python does free up memory when left alone for a long time. If that is not possible, check out mod_python. It eliminates the need for socket communication and ESL completely leaving out the issue. I wasn't able to load test it, but since ESL and TCP server aren't involved, I believe the memory consumption shouldn't go as high.